# Know device lock state at Today extension first appearance (init)

Tags: ios, today-extension

I have a Today extension which change state depending of the device lock state (locked/unlocked).

In order to know if the device is locked/unlocked the first time the extension launch I have an utility function checking if it can read a protected file.
After that, two observers are set on `.UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecome(Un/A)vailable`.

Problem: when you lock the device, there seems to be a 2.5 sec delay before protected files become actually protected, hence preventing me to know the actual state of the device.

How to know the lock state of the device before you have observers set?

Comment: Using a mix of `UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeA/UN` and access to protected file with a stateMachine solved it, but painfully for something looking simple.